# Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, captcha, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

I am trying to put ReCaptcha in registration form (ASP.NET MVC).

```
@Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
```

I have entered private and public keys from ReCaptcha into Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ReCaptchaPrivateKey" value="6LcMwPESAAAAAFyxyxyxyxyxyxy"/>
    <add key="ReCaptchaPublicKey" value="6LcMwPESAAAAAGVyxyxyxyxyxyxy"/>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

But it is giving this error:

> Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid

How to solve this problem?

PS. I have read CoffeeCup solution [here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/input-error-k-format-of-site-key-was-invalid/). But could not solve problem in that way in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recaptcha with ASP.NET MVC can very easily be implemented under a minute using this nuget extension - [Recaptcha for .NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RecaptchaNet/1.3.0)

I was able to set up one and have blogged about the same here - [Implementing reCAPTCHA in your ASP.NET MVC Project](http://yassershaikh.com/implementing-recaptcha-in-your-asp-net-mvc-project/)

Below is a summary of the same....

First you **register** and get your public and private key. (this step you seem to have already done with)

**Install** "Recaptcha for .NET" using NuGet Package Manager, Make sure you download the one shown in the screenshot below as there were plenty others with the same name.
[image: http://yassershaikh.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/step2-recaptcha-nuget-aspnetmvc.png]

**Add the Recaptcha Control to Your MVC View**

Open your `Views/Account/Register` view and add this to the top of the page

```
@using Recaptcha.Web.Mvc
```

and include the recaptcha form using the following razor code

```
<li>
    @Html.Label("Some label to go here")
    @Html.Recaptcha()
</li>
```

**Verify User's Response to Recaptcha Challenge in your Controller/Action**

Next step is to configure recaptcha in your **controller/action**, start with importing the following namespaces in your controller file (AccountController for this example)

```
using Recaptcha.Web;
using Recaptcha.Web.Mvc;
```

Next, go to your Register method and use the following code

```
RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaHelper.Response))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Captcha answer cannot be empty.");
    return View(model);
}

RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse();

if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect captcha answer.");
}
```

Here is how the recaptcha form looks on my register page where I setup using the above code.

[image]

Hope this helps.